# Find out where the error happened in Clojure

Tags: clojure, runtime-error

For the most part I understand what Clojure is telling me with it's error messages. But I am still clueless as to find out where the error happened.

**Here is an example of what I mean**

```
(defn extract [m]
  (keys m))

(defn multiple [xs]
  (map #(* 2 %) xs))

(defn process [xs]
  (-> xs
      (multiple)     ; seq -> seq
      (extract))) ; map -> seq ... fails

(process [1 2 3])
```

Statically typed languages would now tell me that I tried to pass a sequence to a function that expects a map on line X. And Clojure does this in a way:

```
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry
```

But I still have no idea where the error happened. Obviously for this instance it's easy because there are just 3 functions involved, you can easily just read through all of them but as programs grow bigger this gets old very quickly.

Is there a way find out where the errors happened other than just proof reading the code from top to bottom? (which is my current approach)

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Sorry that was a mistake. Forgot to swap it. I meant `multiple`.

Comment: What is your expected output here? keys should be used with maps you are passing vector into that one. like -> (keys [2 4 6]) which does not work.Check the keys function here: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys. 

Also (map #(* 2 %) xs) does not generate hash-maps.Also see map: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map

Comment: It was demonstration of a mistake, I know what `keys` does. I even explained why the error happened. My expected output is something that tells me where the error happened.

Comment: Just a small thing - where there are no arguments you don't need the surrounding parens to the call, for example `(multiple)` could just be `multiple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use clojure.spec. It is still in alpha, and there's still a bunch of tooling support coming (hopefully), but instrumenting functions works well.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require
   ;; For clojure 1.9.0-alpha16 and higher, it is called spec.alpha
   [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
   [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]))


;; Extract takes a map and returns a seq
(s/fdef extract
  :args (s/cat :m map?)
  :ret seq?)

(defn extract [m]
  (keys m))


;; multiple takes a coll of numbers and returns a coll of numbers
(s/fdef multiple
  :args (s/cat :xs (s/coll-of number?))
  :ret (s/coll-of number?))

(defn multiple [xs]
  (map #(* 2 %) xs))


(defn process [xs]
  (-> xs
      (multiple)     ; seq -> seq
      (extract))) ; map -> seq ... fails

;; This needs to come after the definition of the specs,
;; but before the call to process.
;; This is something I imagine can be handled automatically
;; by tooling at some point.
(stest/instrument)

;; The println is to force evaluation.
;; If not it wouldn't run because it's lazy and
;; not used for anything.
(println (process [1 2 3]))
```

Running this file prints (among other info):

```
Call to #'foo.core/extract did not conform to spec: In: [0] val: (2
4 6) fails at: [:args :m] predicate: map?  :clojure.spec.alpha/spec
#object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__1200 0x2b935f0d
"clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__1200@2b935f0d"]
:clojure.spec.alpha/value ((2 4 6)) :clojure.spec.alpha/args ((2 4
6)) :clojure.spec.alpha/failure :instrument
:clojure.spec.test.alpha/caller {:file "core.clj", :line 29,
:var-scope foo.core/process}
```

Which can be read as: A call to `exctract` failed because the value passed in `(2 4 6)` failed the predicate `map?`. That call happened in the file `"core.clj"` at line 29.

A caveat that trips people up is that instrument only checks function arguments and not return values. This is a (strange if you ask me) design decision from Rich Hickey. There's [a library for that, though](https://github.com/jeaye/orchestra).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a REPL session you can print a stack trace:

```
(clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace *e 30)
```

See http://puredanger.github.io/tech.puredanger.com/2010/02/17/clojure-stack-trace-repl/ for various different ways of printing the stack trace. You will need to have a dependency such as this in your `project.clj`:

```
[org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]
```

I didn't get a stack trace using the above method, however just typing `*e` at the REPL will give you all the available information about the error, which to be honest didn't seem very helpful.

For the rare cases where the stack trace is not helpful I usually debug using a call to a function that returns the single argument it is given, yet has the side effect of printing that argument. I happen to call this function `probe`. In your case it can be put at multiple places in the threading macro.

Comment: `*e` tells me where the error happened in the base library. But I'd like to see where the error happened in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Re-typing your example I have:

```
(defn extract [m]
  (keys m))

(defn multiply [xs]
  (mapv #(* 2 %) xs))

(defn process [xs]
  (-> xs
    (multiply)      ; seq -> seq
    (extract)))     ; map -> seq ... fails ***line 21***

(println (process [1 2 3]))
;=> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast 
to java.util.Map$Entry, compiling:(tst/clj/core.clj:21:21)
```

So we get a good clue in the exception where is says the file and line/col number `tst.clj.core.clj:21:21` that the `extract` method is the problem.

Another indispensible tool I use is Plumatic Schema to inject "gradual" type checking into clojure.  The code becomes:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]
    [schema.core :as s]))
(t/refer-tupelo)
(t/print-versions)

(s/defn extract :- [s/Any]
  [m :- tsk/Map]
  (keys m))

(s/defn multiply :- [s/Num]
  [xs :- [s/Num]]
  (mapv #(* 2 %) xs))

(s/defn process :- s/Any
  [xs :- [s/Num]]
  (-> xs
    (multiply) ; seq -> seq
    (extract))) ; map -> seq ... fails

(println (process [1 2 3])) 

clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Input to extract does not match schema: 
[(named (not (map? [2 4 6])) m)] {:type :schema.core/error, :schema [#schema.core.One{:schema {Any Any}, 
:optional? false, :name m}], 
:value [[2 4 6]], :error [(named (not (map? [2 4 6])) m)]}, 
compiling:(tst/clj/core.clj:23:17)
```

So, while the format of the error message is a bit lengthy, it tells right away that we passed a parameter of the wrong type and/or shape into the method `extract`.

Note that you need a line like this:

```
(s/set-fn-validation! true) ; enforce fn schemas
```

I create a special file `test/tst/clj/_bootstrap.clj` so it is always in the same place.

For more information on Plumatic Schema please see:

- https://github.com/plumatic/schema
- https://youtu.be/o_jtwIs2Ot8
- https://github.com/plumatic/schema/wiki/Basics-Examples
- https://github.com/plumatic/schema/wiki/Defining-New-Schema-Types-1.0

Comment: I didn't get a line number just the exception. How do you set things up to get a line number? Since my post I've looked into spec. It's probably wiser to focus on what will be standard in Clojure at some point?

Comment: Re line #: I don't use the repl much so I just put everything in a file and use `lein test`. Re spec: I think Schema is easier to use, and it is quite widespread. It is almost a "standard" like Ring, etc.